# Seaborn plt.savefigure 'overwriting images'

Tags: python, graph, png, seaborn

## Problem

I'm trying to save graphs with seaborn and matplotlib plt.savefig('.png'), but what is happening is that the graphs are being overwritten, even when the name is different. I can't use

`fig = sns.lineplot(data=totaldf, palette="tab10", linewidth=2.5) 
fig.savefig('.png')`

because it returns:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'

How can I save this graphs without overwrite?

## Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

maindf = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
maindf['M01']=(maindf['M01'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M02']=(maindf['M02'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M03']=(maindf['M03'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M04']=(maindf['M04'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M05']=(maindf['M05'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M06']=(maindf['M06'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M07']=(maindf['M07'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M08']=(maindf['M08'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M09']=(maindf['M09'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M10']=(maindf['M10'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M11']=(maindf['M11'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M12']=(maindf['M12'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M13']=(maindf['M13'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M14']=(maindf['M14'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
maindf['M15']=(maindf['M15'].apply(lambda x: x * 27))
index=0
totaldf = pd.DataFrame({ 'Pontuacao Total':maindf.sum(axis=1)})
sns.countplot(totaldf['Pontuacao Total'])
plt.savefig("PontuacaoTotalDistPlot.png")
sns.heatmap(totaldf,cmap = 'inferno_r')
plt.savefig('PontuacaoTotalHeatmap.png')
sns.lineplot(data=totaldf, palette="tab10", linewidth=2.5)
plt.savefig('PontuacaoTotalLine.png')
```

## Images

#### That's the lineplot

[image: That's the line plot]

#### That's the heatmap

[image: That's the heatmap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new figure for each plot,

```
plt.figure()
sns.countplot(...)
plt.savefig(...)

plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(...)
plt.savefig(...)
```

You can also save any specific figure,

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
sns.countplot(...)

fig2 = plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(...)

fig1.savefig(...)
fig2.savefig(...)
```